# How to allow tea4cups runing from cups backend to write in tmp directory?

Tags: macos, permissions, backend, cups, tmp

I followed the Tea4cups install procedure, and adapt it to a Mac OS High Sierra. 
It's running CUPS 2.2.5.
I'm having issue when trying to write in /tmp directory (it's a symlink to /private/tmp/ directory.

Tried to change tmp directory permission, with no luck.
Logged in as user1, i'm able to create directories, files in this folder from a terminal.

When activating debug log, i get this issue:

D [23/Jul/2019:10:12:57 +0200] [Job 20] Tea4CUPS v3.12_official (PID 919) : Launching posthook_0 : cat $TEADATAFILE >/tmp/cid-$TEAUSERNAME-$TEAJOBID.ps
D [23/Jul/2019:10:12:57 +0200] [Job 20] sh: /tmp/cid-user1-20.ps: Operation not permitted
D [23/Jul/2019:10:12:57 +0200] [Job 20] Tea4CUPS v3.12_official (PID 918) : Exit code for posthook posthook_0 (PID 919) on printer MyPrinter is 1
E [23/Jul/2019:10:12:57 +0200] [Job 20] Tea4CUPS v3.12_official (PID 918) : Posthook posthook_0 (PID 919) on printer MyPrinter didn\'t exit successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the cups user (at least thats the user cups is running under in Archlinux) is able to write to that folder. Otherwise, try a different folder.